# Empty Cursor when querying contact uri

Tags: android, uri, android-contacts, contactscontract

My little test app picks one contact using the contact picker:

```
    final Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

in the onActivityResult method, I parse the result and it's something like `content://com.android.contacts/data/7557`. I then query this uri to get its name and lookup key:

```
final String[] projection = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY };
final Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    final String lookupKey = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY));
    Log.d(TAG, "picked contact, name: " + name + ", lookup key: " + lookupKey);
}
```

It works fine, but not for SOME contacts. Some contacts will result in an empty cursor.
I checked out other questions. This one seems to have the same problem [querying contacts - SOMETIMES returns empty cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823097/android-querying-contacts-sometimes-returns-empty-cursor) (but no answers). I tried the approach of the solution proposed in this question, [Retrieve Contact Phone Number From URI in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370628/retrieve-contact-phone-number-from-uri-in-android):

```
final String id = contactUri.getLastPathSegment();
final String[] whereArgs = new String[] { id };
final Cursor c2 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ?", whereArgs, null);
if (c2.moveToFirst()) {
    final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    final String lookupKey = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY));
}
```

but unfortunately the problem stays: SOME contacts will result in an empty cursor. 
What am I doing wrong? Thanks anybody for the help.

Comment: checking cursor is null or not? before moving cursor to the first result from contentResolver may help. if(c!=null){//Move cursor to first} else {//return no contacts found}. Hope it works! :)

Comment: cursor is never null, just empty.

Comment: I ended up using a workaround, getting the phone number from the extra bundle `final String phoneNumber = data.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");`