# Empty cursor when querying contact uri from phone and Google account

Tags: android, contacts, google-contacts-api

my app must picks one contact.

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent pickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(pickContact, REQUEST_CONTACT);
            }
        });

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT && intent != null) {
            Uri contactUri = intent.getData();
            String[] queryFields = new String[]{Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY} ;
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, queryFields, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                c.moveToFirst();
                String contact = c.getString(0);
                mButton.setText(contact);
            } finally {
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

But it works fine only with contacts stored in my phone. If contact stored in Google account, it wouldn't work. I'll get empty cursor. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111003/empty-cursor-when-querying-contact-uri) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823097/querying-contacts-sometimes-returns-empty-cursor). And i've read [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts). These methods are completely different. What should i do if i want get data from any contacts (Google, phone, sim) by pressing single button?

Comment: what is your `contactUri` you want to `query`?

Comment: i think Contacts.CONTENT_URI. Here `Intent pickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(pickContact, REQUEST_CONTACT);` For my purposes I need only the name of the contact.

Comment: so you dont know that? just call `Log.d` inside `onActivityResult` and watch the logcat

Comment: `import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;`

Comment: call `Log.d(TAG, "uri: " +  intent.getData());` inside `onActivityResult` and watch the logcat

Comment: `01-12 14:19:29.846 26190-26190/com.example.hogust.criminalintent D/TAG: uri: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/3789r326-5C0A7C346CBA0A.1853i326/1309
01-12 14:21:03.986 26190-26190/com.example.hogust.criminalintent D/TAG: uri: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2408i6955d55a890e0f92/108` the first gives an empty cursor. the second is all right.

Comment: try this http://pastebin.com/be8RPCAN and watch the logcat again

Comment: `01-12 14:29:44.566 26190-26190/com.example.hogust.criminalintent D/TAG: onActivityResult all data uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/3789r326-5C0A7C346CBA0A.1853i326/1309/data
01-12 14:30:12.666 26190-26190/com.example.hogust.criminalintent D/TAG: onActivityResult all data uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2408i6955d55a890e0f92/108/data
`

Comment: what does `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);` show (line 16 in the code)?

Comment: in debugger i found this `    >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@41bd0f08`

Comment: so `c.getCount()` == 0?

Comment: WOW!!! It works perfectly. So, what is my mistake? Generally it was the task from the book.

Comment: i have no idea what book you mean

Comment: In any case, thank you very much.